# Merging multiple columns with different column lengths

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have the following two dataframes:

```
values = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': ['A', 'C', 'B'], 
                     'val2': [None, 'A', None], 
                     'val3': [None, 'B', 'A']},
                     index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3]))

desc = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                    'description': ['Description for A', 'Description for B', 'Description for C', 'Description for D']},
                    index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

|  | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | None | None |
| 2 | C | A | B |
| 3 | B | None | A |

|  | value | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Description for A |
| 2 | B | Description for B |
| 3 | C | Description for C |
| 4 | D | Description for D |

How do I merge the two dataframes I keep the left table, and for each column, I am joining the description from the right table?

|  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val1_desc | val2_desc | val3_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | None | None | Description for A | None | None |
| 2 | C | A | B | Description for C | Description for A | Description for B |
| 3 | B | None | A | Description for B | None | Description for A |

I've tried

```
pd.merge(values, desc, how='left', left_on=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], right_on=['value'])
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

Comment: simply merge on the columns that are common to both data frames : ``values.merge(desc, left_on='val1', right_on='value')``. of course, you can modify it to fit your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to flip `values` into long form, merge with `desc`, pivot back to wide form, and make adjustments to the columns:

```
df = (values.melt(ignore_index=False)
            .reset_index()
            .merge(desc, on='value')
            .rename(columns={"description":"desc", "value":""})
            .pivot('index', 'variable')
            .swaplevel(axis='columns')
     )
```

Flatten the columns:

```
 df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)
```

Some more cleanup, before the final output:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda df: df.rstrip("_")).rename_axis(index=None)

  val1 val2 val3          val1_desc          val2_desc          val3_desc
1    A  NaN  NaN  Description for A                NaN                NaN
2    C    A    B  Description for C  Description for A  Description for B
3    B  NaN    A  Description for B                NaN  Description for A
```